# What game am I looking for?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, rhyme

Normally a nuke is delivered by missile or plane
But not this time, as it was on a train
Like a mirage, a mushroom in the sky
Overpassing the clouds, so high
I begin to experience vertigo
Witnessing this huge inferno
Only to be reduced to dust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm. Could it be

> counter-strike?

because

> Each line seems to include the name of a map, namely:
>  de_nuke, de_train, de_mirage, de_overpass, de_vertigo, de_inferno, de_dust

and of course

> The entire paragraph is about blowing up, which is the case for all de_ (bomb DEfusal) maps

Comment: rot13: Gur nafjre vf pbeerpg ohg pybhqf vf abg n pf znc, ng yrnfg abar gung V nz njner bs. Gurer vf nabgure znc va gung yvar.

Comment: OK, did a little search and added it in. Haven't played that one.